# Using Rules to check NonBlank entries in QGIS

Tags: qgis, rule-based

I am trying use Rules in Symbology to display entries based on a criteria. The criteria is display only those entries which have a date associated with them. I have table of points which has Date field along with Coordinates( Lat/long) for each entry. Some points have date field empty and some has valid dates. My idea is to display only those points which have a valid date entry.

Comment: An example of a "valid date entry" in your case? Edit the question

Answer (score 2):

I considered your date format is something like `2012-05-04` and is a string

You can use the following in the rules to check if  not null or not empty and check then if date is valid

```
("datecol" IS NOT NULL OR "datecol" <> '')
AND regexp_match(
datecol, ''[0-3][0-9]/[01][0-9]/[12][09][0-9]*'') > 0
```

Comment: hello date format used in my data set is: 09/04/2021

Comment: Edited my regex to match your format